# Change Ionic Tabs to navigate to their root page and not to their last page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using the Ionic Tab Navigation

```
<ion-tabs #mainTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1" tabTitle="Page1" tabIcon="icon-tasks"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2" tabTitle="Page2" tabIcon="icon-calendar"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3" tabTitle="Page3" tabIcon="icon-profile"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And everything works okay with the exception that when I click on a tab it goes to the last visited page on that stack and not the root page of the stack.

For example:

```
Page1
  Subpage1 (root)
  Subpage2
  Subpage3 <-- Last visited page
Page2
Page3
```

If I am on the last visited page (Subpage3) then I touch on tab Page3 and then I touch on tab for Page1 it goes back to Subpage3 but I want it to go to Subpage1 which is root.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This questions is similar to this other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630946/ionic-4-tabbar-how-to-always-show-tab-root-instead-tab-sub-pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Altenative approch on Ionic 5***

.html

```
<ion-tabs (ionTabsDidChange)="setRootTab($event)">
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="schedule">
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Schedule</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="speakers">
      <ion-icon name="person-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Speakers</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
 
</ion-tabs>
```

*.ts*

```
 setRootTab(event: any): void {
    switch (event?.tab) {
      case 'schedule':
           
          this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/schedule');

        break;

      case 'speakers':
        this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/speakers');

        break;

    

      default:
    }
  }
```

***It is by Design***

This is by design.In other words, Each individual `ion-tab` is a declarative component for a `NavController`.So if you push something to that `tab's` `NavController`, it remains there when you'll come back again to that Tab.

> NavController is the base class for navigation controller components
> like Nav and Tab. You use navigation controllers to navigate to pages
> in your app. At a basic level, a navigation controller is an array of
> pages representing a particular history (of a Tab for example). This
> array can be manipulated to navigate throughout an app by pushing and
> popping pages or inserting and removing them at arbitrary locations in
> history.

Please see the [**Doc for more info**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: this being by design does not mean it is not possible to achieve what OP is asking. In fact, @Salva Bordas answer does work as requested

Comment: Always be careful of saying "cannot" as a developer! :D

Comment: This behavior is VERY ODD! It should be configurable at least. Ionic v5 still has this issue.
This solution hack its around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59632336/3317037
For reference, this is the exact Ionic line of code which handles this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/3c1be89112d464e77d65c875223138aaedf350cd/angular/src/directives/navigation/ion-tabs.ts#L126

Comment: @daymannovaes It is super easy to change. Please see the update above.

Comment: @Sampath thanks for the update. It works, but unfortunately is still a hacky way around Ionic odd behavior.

Answer (score 10):

Like Sampath comments this is by design. The only way i found is to force it by a ion-tab change event:

```js
tabChanged($ev) {
  $ev.setRoot($ev.root);
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs #mainTabs (ionChange)="tabChanged($event)">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1" tabTitle="Page1" tabIcon="icon-tasks"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2" tabTitle="Page2" tabIcon="icon-calendar"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3" tabTitle="Page3" tabIcon="icon-profile"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: i think you forgot the event parameter (ionChange)="clickTab($event)"

Comment: This does not work in Ionic 4. It would be `(ionTabsDidChange)="tabChanged($event)` but the event is of type `CustomEvent<{tab: string}>` which has no `root` or `setRoot`.

Comment: Where did you put the code of the `tabChanged($ev) {
  $ev.setRoot($ev.root);
}` ?

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this for an Ionic v1 app?   Is it even possible to do in v1?  Trying to fix an old app that is using a `$state.go("tabRoot")` to force a tabs child view back to parent/root view when the menu tab button is clicked - it works but its ugly because you do see the child view transition back to the parent view.  I can't find any other method to get the tab back to the root view after the user leaves child view to another tab...and then back to the tab in question.

Comment: Also this does not work in Ionic v5, but this answer does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630946/ionic-4-tabbar-how-to-always-show-tab-root-instead-tab-sub-pages

Answer (score 1):

So i did this to fix in latest angular and ionic

```
 <ion-tab-button (click)="appointments()" tab="appointments">
```

And our appointments() function in ts is:

```
appointments(): void {                  
  this.router.navigate(['/customer/appointments']);
}
```

Pretty simple, we just route on our needed page, and no this weird last page opened.

Answer (score -1):

Use this.navCtrl.popToRoot() function on every subpage.
You can find more about it here. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: This does not exist in Ionic 4.

Comment: @Russ There are only **Ionic 2** and **Ionic 3** tags specified by the OP.

Comment: Understood. Just adding information for those in Ionic4 that come to this page.

Comment: `popToRoot` does exist in ionic 4 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/b31b9f45de1496432561a583843e6166f9aa53f5/core/src/components/nav/readme.md

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
this.navCtrl.goBack();//for ionic 4
this.navCtrl.pop(); //ionic 3
```

As pop or goback would pop out the last visted page out of the stack

Comment: Yes, but you would see the transition.